# How to have NUnit collection comparison invoke ToString when there is a discrepancy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am using VS 2010, and running my unit tests with NUnit. The following line correctly detects if two lists differ:

```
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

However, I would like a better error message than the following:

```
Expected and actual are both <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.MyClass]> with 2 elements
  Values differ at index [0]
  Expected: <MyNamespace.MyClass>
  But was:  <MyNamespace.MyClass>
```

In MyNamespace.MyClass, I have implemented the following method:

```
public new string ToString()
```

I would expect NUnit to output the following:

```
Expected and actual are both <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.MyClass]> with 2 elements
  Values differ at index [0]
  Expected: <24 ounces of cold beer>
  But was:  <2.4 ounces of rotten tomatoes>
```

However, NUnit does not invoke it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've *hidden* the method from `object` instead of *overriding* it. Use this:

```
public override string ToString()
```

Basically NUnit is just calling `object.ToString()` - which you hadn't overridden. Unless it specifically looked for a *new* method with reflection, it wouldn't find your one - and overriding is the idiomatic way to do this. Was this just a simple mistake, or did you *mean* to shadow the method for some reason?

Comment: new instead of override was just a typo